# Use copy module in playbook with variables

Tags: variables, ansible, copy

I am trying to write a playbook that will let me copy any file on my local machine to any location on the destination machine. Permissions aren't an issue because the copy source and destination are within the permissions of the user.

In all examples I see for the copy module, the source, and destination are hard-coded into the playbook as such:

```yaml
tasks:

  - name: stuff
    copy:
      src: /my/path/file.name
      dest: /my/remote/path/file.name
```

That is all well and good, except it hardcodes things that I want to set on the command line with `--extra-vars`. My need is to be able to define the source file and destination on the command line so I can copy any file to any destination with the same playbook and without modifications to the playbook.

How do I set up the playbook to accept variables for both src and dest, so I can use this sort of command line to call it?

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook -e "host_list=myhosts srcvar=/my/path/file.name destvar=/my/remote/path/file.name" playbook.yml
```

I've tried using the Jinja2 notation `src: "{{ srcvar }}"` and `dest: "{{ destvar }}"` in the playbook and then calling it on the command line with

```bash
-e "srcvar=/my/path/file.name destvar=/my/remote/path/file.name"
```

, but it gives this error under TASK [Copy files]:

> fatal: [test_server]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'str object' has no attribute 'files'"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project below works as expected

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
└── playbook.yml

0 directories, 3 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[myhosts]
test_11
test_13

[myhosts:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
ansible_perl_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/perl
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: "{{ host_list }}"

  tasks:

    - copy:
        src: "{{ srcvar }}"
        dest: "{{ destvar }}"
```

```bash
shell> ll /tmp/file.name 
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3248 Feb  4 03:26 /tmp/file.name
```

copied the file to the remote hosts

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e "host_list=myhosts srcvar=/tmp/file.name destvar=/tmp/file.name" playbook.yml

PLAY [myhosts] *******************************************************************************

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 ls -la /tmp/file.name
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  3248 Feb  4 02:35 /tmp/file.name
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 ls -la /tmp/file.name
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  3248 Feb  4 02:35 /tmp/file.name
```

The play is idempotent

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e "host_list=myhosts srcvar=/tmp/file.name destvar=/tmp/file.name" playbook.yml

PLAY [myhosts] *******************************************************************************

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_13]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Notes:

- You can use the option `-e` multiple times making the command easier to read and less error-prone (probably)

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook -e "host_list=myhosts" -e "srcvar=/tmp/file.name" -e "destvar=/tmp/file.name" playbook.yml
```

- You can put the parameters into a YAML file

```yaml
shell> cat params.yml 
host_list: myhosts
srcvar: /tmp/file.name
destvar: /tmp/file.name
```

and use it in the command

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook -e @params.yml playbook.yml
```